# ionic: cyclical dependency and cannot resolve all parameters for

Tags: ionic-framework, circular-dependency, injectable

I have a component (ItemDetailsPage) that is importing a helper service

```
import { Helper } from './../../app/Helper';
```

and in the constructor I have

```
constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
    public helper: Helper...)
```

In Helper.ts I have the following:

```
import { ItemDetailsPage } from './../pages/item-details/item-details';
```

and I use it like that:

```
showItemWindow() {
    let itemModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ItemDetailsPage, null, { cssClass: "modal-fullscreen" });
    itemModal.present();
}
```

When doing the above, I get "cannot resolve all parameters for ItemDetailsPage... I understand that it's because of a circular dependency. I can move `showItemWindow` to another component and it works but the reason I put it in the helper, is because I need it from 3 different pages and I wanted one place to open this window.

Is there another cleaner solution for this or moving it to 3 different component is the right one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notice how you have 3 periods `...` after your declaration of the `Helper` class in the constructor.Your constructor method should look like below.

```
constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
    public helper: Helper)
```